# Flask random less than symbol on page

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, jinja2

I have a really annoying problem where "<" is displayed on my templates. [Right at the very top of the web page is this annoying "<" symbol.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmUeF.jpg)  Could anyone please tell me what the cause of it is.

Comment: Please copy and paste instead of a screen shot. It would be easier for us.

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `&lt; or &gt;` for display symbols < or >

Answer (score 0):

You may having some html tag or attribute which never closed. But most probably it's because you have some wrong or unsupported value on any of your attribute. But how can someone check, you don't share any sample code or demo link

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm very new to this, but here is the files for my application. https://github.com/nathan-abuaku/personalsite

Comment: I don't have environment installed to check your project on live. But your project have some issues which you can check and solved by [link](https://validator.w3.org/). Ex. You have `li` inside another `li`, you have several attribute on tags without having space between them etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an extra opening HTML tag somewhere. You can try to search through your code using your editors CTRL+F and look for "<<". I would look for the problem in your HTML.